# How would I deploy a WPF MVVM project with Entity Framework and Oracle Db?

Tags: c#, wpf, oracle, entity-framework, mvvm

I have developed a project in WPF MVVM framework. The database part is Entity Framework and the database is Oracle 11g. When I run the .exe application in the machine where I developed it, it runs perfect but when I run it in another machine it becomes 'Not Responding'.
I have tried to include the following dlls:
-oci.dll
-ociw32.dll
-orannzsbb11.dll
-oraocci11.dll
But the "Add Reference" in Visual Studio is not allowing me to add the above references.
What all dlls I need to include in the solution so that it runs perfect on user's machine?

Comment: You will need to install an oracle client on each machine where the application will be used. Either an Instant Client install or a regular client install. Just including DLLs will not work.

Comment: The laptop on which i am trying to install has Oracle SQL developer, what other client do i need to install can you please suggest?

Comment: @SormitaChakraborty SQL*Developer is not an Oracle Client. It is just an IDE which using a different way to connect to remote database. whereas oracle client, gives you the native support of oracle tools to be accessed from remote(like drivers). Like sqlplus, sql loader.. Etc.. Only the oracle client comes with the dlls you look for.

Comment: I have managed to add Oracle.ManagedDataAccess to my application and published it but the problem is it is now asking for Oracle.ManagedDataAccessDTC.dll as prerequisite when i try to install the application, i am not able to find this dll anywhere, how to resolve this?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/html/E41125_02/installODPmd.htm